# Necesito enviar varios parametros a un controlador JSON!

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var appController = (function () {
    return {
             save: function (_item, _tipo) {
                       APP.rq.axios.put(APP.ctrl + '/proyeccion', _item)
             }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es como paso la variable _tipo dentro de la cadena.

Siendo proyeccion el llamado al httpput

item es mi data que se va a grabar.

Quiero pasar ambas variables

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Luis!, realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es **muy importante leer [ask]** que te brinda información de como realizar una pregunta en el sitio, realiza tu pregunta de acuerdo a este documento y obtendrás muy buenas respuestas!, saludos.

Comment: Agrega información adicional, como que bibliotecas usas .. Contextualiza tu problema de forma que se pueda entender.

Comment: Listo encontre la solucion:

Answer (score 0):

```
save: function (_item, _tipo) {
    APP.rq.axios.put(APP.ctrl + '/proyeccion?tipo=' + _tipo, _item)
}
```

Esta es la solucion que buscaba